# Como colocar um RaddioButton como Checked no Razor Page

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, html-select

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, quero deixar esse radioButton como checked, porém o mesmo não fica marcado, ja tentei colocar checked(true), mas não funciona, segue o código:

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Pesquisa,"1")